# Fastest method to accept a byte from a nibble in hardware (8051)

Tags: performance, assembly, optimization, microcontroller, 8051

I have a smaller 8051 microcontroller (AT89C4051) connected to a larger microcontroller (AT89S52) and the larger one is running the clock of the smaller one. The crystal speed for the large one is 22.1184Mhz. Documentation states that because the ALE line is controlling the smaller micro, its clock speed is limited to 3.6Mhz.

The two micros communicate with each other with only 4 I/O lines and one interrupt line. I'm trying to make reception of a byte occur as fast as possible, but the code I have come up with makes me think I didn't choose the best solution, but here is what I got so far:

```
org 0h
ljmp main ;run initialization + program

org 13h         ;INT1 handler - worse case scenario: 52uS processing time I think?
  push PSW      ;save old registers and the carry flag
  mov PSW,#18h  ;load our register space
  mov R7,A      ;save accumulator (PUSH takes an extra clock cycle I think)
  mov A,P1      ;Grab data (wish I could grab it sooner somehow)
  anl A,#0Fh     ;Only lowest 4 bits on P1 is the actual data. other 4 bits are useless
  djnz R2,nonib2   ;See what nibble # we are at. 1st or 2nd?
        orl A,R6   ;were at 2nd so merge previously saved data in
        mov @R0,A  ;and put it in memory space
        inc R0     ;and increment pointer
        mov R2,#2h ;and reset nibble number
  nonib2:
  swap A           ;exchange nibbles to prevent overwriting nibble later
  mov R6,A         ;save to R6 high nibble
  mov A,R7         ;restore accumulator
  pop PSW          ;restore carry and register location
reti               ;return to wherever

main:
  mov PSW,#18h ;use new address for R0 through R7 to not clash with other routines
  mov R1,#BUFCMD ;setup start of buffer space as R1
  mov R2,#2h     ;set # nibbles needed to process byte
  mov PSW,#0h
  mov IE,#84h    ;enable external interrupt 1
  ..rest of code here...
```

We have to assume that this can be triggered by hardware at any point, even during a time-sensitive LCD character processing routine in which all registers and accumulator are used.

What optimizations can I perform to this code here to make it run much faster?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do the nibble processing in the interrupt. Just store the 4 bits as they come in.

Assuming you can allocate R0 globally, the code can be as simple as:

```
org 13h 
mov @r0, p1
inc r0
reti
```

Won't get much faster than that.

If you absolutely can not reserve R0, but you can at least arrange to use register banks differing in a single bit, e.g. #0 and #1, then you can use bit set/clear to switch away and back in 2 cycles, instead of 5 for the `push psw` approach.

Comment: But I will need to do processing because I'm actually transferring bytes through a nibble channel and also, I have my registers used for other purposes. If for example I were in a middle of a memory-to-memory copy operation on the same chip, then I'd be using addresses R0 and R1 to transfer bytes from one space to another and the code you present will then not work for me.

Comment: You can do the processing in normal code. You didn't show any other processing in your interrupt either. As for allocating R0, everything comes at a cost. You can do a memory-to-memory copy without it, it will just be slower. You decide which one you want to make fast, the ISR or the copy ;)